# WordPress Network Installation: How to get the ID of the site being viewed

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Network Site installation with 4 different sub-sites using the sub-directory style: domain.com/ger, domain.com/fra, domain.com/esp, etc.

All the above sites are using the same theme/template.

In one of my files I want to add a couple of lines of custom content depending on which site is being viewed.

So I figured there must be a way of get the ID of the sub-sites when an user views a page and then displaying the content specific to that sub-site.

Something like this, maybe:

```
<?php
If blog_id=2
{
?>
Content specfic to Germany
<?php
}
elseif blog_id=3
{
?>
Content specific to France
<?php
}
?>
```

But I cannot figure out how to get the id of the sub-site when that page loads.

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_current_blog_id()` - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_blog_id

```
$blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

switch ( $blog_id ) {
    case 2:
        // content here...
        break;

    case 3:
        // alternative content...
        break;

    default:
        // content when above IDs aren't matched...
}
```